# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Upstream messages are received twice

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our app sends some messages to our servers via FCM Upstream. We have two servers connected as clients.

Recently, we've noticed that many messages (>50%) are received twice. Often on different servers, but sometimes on the same server.

Unsure where to go from here.

Logs of one message being received twice follow:

```
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 21:39:17 GMT xmpp:connection receive: 
  <message to="xxxx@gcm.googleapis.com" from="devices@gcm.googleapis.com" type="normal">
    <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
      {"data":
        {"userInfo":"{}",
         "path":"v1\/patient\/checkIn\/usage",
         "method":"POST",
         "body":"{}",
         "dest":"https:\/\/api.stg.triggrhealth.com\/api\/v1"
        },
       "time_to_live":43200,
       "from":"f5LDS516Eu8:APA91bGEkzwXlmXRpfui6T01QM6V3pOY8p3nSkZMUfYkDYjRxu6Xa64Bh0Boc3so8X8royBA1v4PaGjPcUW6JI0pcZL7UK9P4LEqgVThfNQKGW8DZMhTEM-JDodDvUPjGpbPA-zdYYQb",
       "message_id":"1479505157658",
       "category":"com.triggrhealth.prototype.stage"
      }
    </gcm>
  </message>
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 21:39:17 GMT xmpp:connection send: 
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
    {"to":"f5LDS516Eu8:APA91bGEkzwXlmXRpfui6T01QM6V3pOY8p3nSkZMUfYkDYjRxu6Xa64Bh0Boc3so8X8royBA1v4PaGjPcUW6JI0pcZL7UK9P4LEqgVThfNQKGW8DZMhTEM-JDodDvUPjGpbPA-zdYYQb",
     "message_id":"1479505157658",
     "message_type":"ack"
    }
  </gcm>
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 21:42:28 GMT xmpp:connection receive: 
  <message to="xxxx@gcm.googleapis.com" from="devices@gcm.googleapis.com" type="normal">
    <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
      {"data":
        {"userInfo":"{}",
         "path":"v1\/patient\/checkIn\/usage",
         "method":"POST",
         "body":"{}",
         "dest":"https:\/\/api.stg.triggrhealth.com\/api\/v1"
        },
       "time_to_live":43200,
       "from":"f5LDS516Eu8:APA91bGEkzwXlmXRpfui6T01QM6V3pOY8p3nSkZMUfYkDYjRxu6Xa64Bh0Boc3so8X8royBA1v4PaGjPcUW6JI0pcZL7UK9P4LEqgVThfNQKGW8DZMhTEM-JDodDvUPjGpbPA-zdYYQb",
       "message_id":"1479505157658",
       "category":"com.triggrhealth.prototype.stage"
      }
    </gcm>
  </message>
Fri, 18 Nov 2016 21:42:28 GMT xmpp:connection send: 
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
    {"to":"f5LDS516Eu8:APA91bGEkzwXlmXRpfui6T01QM6V3pOY8p3nSkZMUfYkDYjRxu6Xa64Bh0Boc3so8X8royBA1v4PaGjPcUW6JI0pcZL7UK9P4LEqgVThfNQKGW8DZMhTEM-JDodDvUPjGpbPA-zdYYQb",
     "message_id":"1479505157658",
     "message_type":"ack"
    }
  </gcm>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check and try [sending an ACK message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream#sending_an_ack_message). As mentioned,

> In response to an upstream message, the app server must use the same connection to send an ACK message containing the unique message ID. **If GCM does not receive an ACK, it may retry sending the message to the app server**.

Here's the sample code:

```
<message id="">
  <gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">
  {
      "to":"REGID",
      "message_id":"m-123"
      "message_type":"ack"
  }
  </gcm>
</message>
```

Lastly, please also see the [XMPP Connection Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#upstream) for more information about upstream message syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if you look at the logs I am ACKing the message immediately.